# Is media pipe is use with deep face for face recognition for better accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mediapipe, yolov8, deepface

I'm using deep face for recognition but the accuracy is not good so I try to implement the media pipe in which I extract the landmarks so I give this to the deep face for better accuracy. Is there any way to do this?

I extract the feature vector from the media pipe but how do I pass this to the deep face? Is there any possible way to do this?

Is media pipe landmark used for deep face for face recognition for better accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

DeepFace already wraps MediaPipe face detector.

```py
result = DeepFace.verify(
   img1_path,
   img2_path,
   detector_backend = "mediapipe"
)
print(result)
```

But if you want to reach its maximum power, then I recommend you to use Facenet facial recognition model and retinaface face detector pair.

```py
result = DeepFace.verify(
   img1_path,
   img2_path,
   model_name="Facenet",
   detector_backend = "retinaface"
)
print(result)
```